# Sitecore 8.2 update 2 authentication failed on MongoDB 3.2

Tags: xdb, mongodb, authentication

I've the following scenario

- Sitecore 8.2 update 2
- MongoDB 3.2

Now, I'm trying to setup authentication to MongoDB, and as soon as I update the mongod.cfg

`security:`
`authorization: enabled`

and the ConnectionStrings.config

`mongodb://myuser:mypassword@MongoServer/Sitecore_Analytics`

An error shows up on Sitecore logs

> Exception: MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException Message: Unable to
>   connect to server MongoServer:27017: Error: 18 -
>   Authentication failed..

However, I've granted myuser proper permissions on the MongoDB Collection

`use Sitecore_Analytics`
`db.createUser( { user: "myuser", pwd: "mypassword", roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "Sitecore_Analytics" } ] } )`

Also, using RoboMongo to connect to the MongoDB works!

Comment: Have you tried restarting the app pool? Also, can you please provide the full connection string? And does the MongoServer correct?

Comment: I've Recycled the AppPool, restarted IIS but no luck. I'll get the ConnectionStrings and add on the question

Comment: Did you create an admin user before creating the new user?

Comment: Yes, I did and I'll try modify based on your answer here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I've a typo in my ConnectionString, and the database Tracking_Contact didn't exist at all in the MongoDB.

However, before figure this out, I did uninstall and install all MongoDB again, and when I first accessed the Sitecore the databases were created and Tracking_Contact was named Cracking_Contact by mistake.

After fix it, and re-apply the permissions accordingly and follow the tips from [Hishaam Namoya](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/users/605/hishaam-namooya), everything start to working!